# On vs over (is using "on" wrong here?)

Tags: prepositions, vocabulary, translation

I know the difference. I know *over* in this case means that the thing covers all or almost all of the other thing, and *on* simply means that the thing is on part of the surface of the other thing. But, is using *on* instead of *over* wrong enough to be called a mistake, when the situation fulfills the sense of *over*? For instance: *Zebras have stripes **over** their bodies*. If I replaced *over* with *on*, would it be a wrong word here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over can be used as a preposition, adjective or adverb indicating as across, more than, down, using, other side, during, control, connected with, extra, finished, again, feeling better. Whereas on generally refers to a position which directs to something being on top of something else.

Hence, to answer your question - even if the situaton fulfills the criteria, it is grammatically against the sentence structuring. Hence, I can use "Lay blanket on your sister" but the sentence is incomplete, however "Lay blanket over your sister" gives a foundation to the sentence.
Hence, the context would matter based on the usage of the word on and over

Comment: *"Lay blanket on your sister" but the sentence is incomplete, however "Lay blanket over your sister" gives a foundation to the sentence."* In both of your examples "blanket" requires a determiner, and with the determiner, both are complete sentences. Neither is incomplete. – Greybeard 54 mins ago

Comment: @shreya so, what about *on* in the example I gave above. Would it be wrong?

Comment: @shreya great explanation :)

Answer (score -1):

I think that saying "over their bodies" is a mistake.

("**All over** their bodies" would not be a mistake, as "all over" is an idiom = in every place in/on; [completely] covering; widely distributed.)

> *Medical Tourism: Knowing about Better Medical Treatment* ... " by D.J. Singh. "Also, you are going to get more information about medical practices and services given all over the world,"

> *Over the Edge* "There was blood all over the pillow.")

"Over + object" tends to mean "above + object", i.e. not necessarily (i) touching or (ii) in permanent contact with the object.

To me "*Zebras have stripes over their bodies.*" gives the impression of stripes floating above the zebra's body, or being worn like a coat.

**On** = upon the surface of and implies contact. So *Zebras have stripes **on** their bodies.*

Comment: You explained it with the best of intentions, but I am afraid I have to remind you that *over* in this sense can be interchangeable with that *all over*.

Comment: @FadliSheikh There is a clear difference between "The aircraft flew over the town" and "The aircraft flew all over the town" You may have missed that I put "all over" in brackets - it is an aside. I can only repeat *"Over + object" tends to mean "above + object", i.e. not necessarily (i) touching or (ii) in permanent contact with the object."* Thus your " Zebras have stripes over their bodies." is incorrect as the stripes are **part** of their body.

Comment: but we are not talking about that *over*. I have limited the question to one particular sense. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @FadliSheikh *but we are not talking about that over.* I'm afraid we are: "over" is pretty much univocal - "in a superior position to"